# PyDev: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, pydev

I am trying to redirect all the output to file and set the `stdout` back to default so I can see further debug logs and errors in my terminal. After I noticed that the outfile was `0 KB` when an exception is raised, I handled it using `with`, so it closes the file and allowing me to see what's in there:

```
with open(outfile, 'w+') as o:
    sys.stdout = o

    print('First Line')
    print('Second Line')
    print('Third Line')

    raise Exception("Raised an exception deliberately")        ........(1)

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__                                    ........(2)
print("End")
```

It works as expected but with an additional error:

```
Exception: Raised an exception deliberately
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-72e8db6af18d>", line 1, in <module>
    print('PyDev console: using IPython 6.4.0\n')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

So I also tried this (although it's almost equivalent to what with does in itself):

```
try:
    sys.stdout = open(outfile, 'w+')

    print('First Line')
    print('Second Line')
    print('Third Line')

    raise Exception("Raised an exception deliberately")

finally:
    sys.stdout.close()

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

And the same exception is caught.

Amazingly

```
finally:
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

fixes the problem.

It seems the error thrown is at the *unintended* `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` line, although that line is unreachable (due to explicit `raise` statement which is not caught). And it does not seem right to wrap the rest of the code inside `finally`, or to use `try` and `finally` when we can use `with`, does it?

---

**Why is this happening?**

I have these questions in particular:

1. Firstly, why is the exception not written inside the file?
2. And then, why is (2) complaining about closed file? Is the command not to assign `__stdout__` to `sys.stdout`. I don't understand how this is related to `o`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 things which aren't good:

1. You have to keep what was in `stdout`, not restore `sys.__stdout__` (to make sure it's consistent).
2. You have to reassign to the original before closing your own file (to avoid the point where it may write to your closed file).

i.e.:

```
with open(...) as stream:
    original = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = stream
    try:
        ...
    finally:
        sys.stdout = original
```

Comment: this solves the problem, can you give an insight of why and how `I/O operation on closed file` is happening? Why is it that the assignment operation on variable would want to throw this error?

Comment: Because you're trying to write to the file you opened after closing it.

Comment: Humm, rereading I think that `sys.__stdout__` is already closed in your use case (probably something IPython is doing -- I can't really replicate your use can on a regular run, so, I'm assuming this is the case).